# Inverse of hermitian operator

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

If $A$ is hermitian operator on finite-dimensional inner-product vector space $V$, than prove $A^{-1}$ is also hermitian operator.

( Hermitian operator $A$ is operator such that $A=A^{*}$ )

Comment: So you're.  supposed to show $(A^{-1})^* = A^{-1}$ It's just two steps to complete this identity so begin playing with and trying to rewrite $(A^{-1})^* $

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that $(A^*)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^*$. In order to show that this is the case, it suffices to show that
$$
A^*(A^{-1})^* = I
$$

Comment: I think i solved it. $\langle T^{-1}(x),y\rangle=\langle T^{-1}(x),T(T^{-1}(y))\rangle=\langle T(T^{-1}(x)),T^{-1}(y)\rangle=\langle x,T^{-1}(y)\rangle$.

Comment: That certainly is the direct way to answer the question.